# How to solve the loop in cin.fail()

Tags: c++

Any idea why this happen?

[sample run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1auyH.png)

```
void askNQ(int &noq)
{
    bool x = true;
    while (x)
    {
        int i;
        cout << "How many questions would you like(out of " << noq << ")?" << endl;
        cin >> i;

        if (cin.fail())
        {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Sorry, that is not valid." << endl;
        x = true;
        }
        else if (i > noq)
        {
            cout << "Sorry, that is too many." << endl;
            x = true;
        }
        else if (i <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Sorry, that is too less." << endl;
            x= true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't modify `noq`, why on earth is it passed by reference?

Comment: yah the noq is passed by reference. noq may be the problem?

Comment: It's not the cause of your problem, it's just a pointless pass-by-reference. Passing an `int` by ref is more costly than passing it value. You'd do it if you need to modify it, but you don't.

Answer (score 1):

`cin.ignore();` is in fact a call to `cin.ignore(1, char_traits<char>::eof());`.

So you aren't cleaning the buffer out of any leftover newlines.

The following should fix your problem:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

It clears the next newline character, no matter how far it is in the buffer (for all practical purposes).

Answer (score 0):

You should enter numeric in command line, Since the variable "i" is integer.